# can you make a mud cake using cooked quinoa instead of normal wheat flours

Tags: substitutions

I have been told you can make a mud cake substituting cooked quinoa for normal wheat flours. Is this possible and do you need to add anything else?

Comment: Hi Naomi, welcome to Seasoned Advice. It looks to me like you want to use quinoa instead of wheat flour as opposed to the other way around. I edited your question because it seemed to read the other way. If I'm in error, feel free to click "edit" under the word "substitution" to change it back.

Comment: "Mud Cake" means different things to different people. Could you post a recipe so we can all be on the same page?

Comment: I'm with Jolene. What's a mud cake?

Comment: This isn't a cake, it's a [mousse](http://www.hubertkeller.com/recipes/mod/recipe_317ChocolateQuinoa.html) from Hurbert Keller. When I saw it I thought of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Making substitutions to baking usually requires a bit of experimentation, so unless you're set on converting a particular recipe, your best option is to start with a recipe that is designed to use it.  There are tons of chocolate quinoa cake recipes on the internet.

If you are hoping to convert a favourite recipe to gluten-free (the usual point of these cake recipes), then the proportions of the recipes I looked at are generally similar to flour cake recipes (2 cups cooked quinoa for a 2-layer cake), but the cake batters are mixed in a blender or food processor instead.  I assume this is to make the quinoa finer, more similar in texture to flour.